# HDMI Connection Keeps dropping when laptop unplugged from charging

Tags: laptop, hdmi, power-management, asus-laptop

I project my laptop's screen to my TV with an HDMI cable. So this problem started recently.

If the laptop's not connected to the charging cable, the connection keeps resetting. If I plug the charging cable back in, the issue goes away.

See a demo of the problem here ---> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDe5qhNnuk0

This does not happen with my other laptop.
Things I tried without success:

- Updating/uninstalling the display driver
- Changing HDMI cable
- Reinstalling Windows

Laptop Specs : [ASUS Vivobook S14](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S14-S410UN/specifications/)
OS: Windows 10
HDMI cable : Not gold plated

Any ideas how to mitigate this? Thanks

Comment: When you say recently, how recent are we talking? Have you had any updates prior to the issue e.g. Windows Updates?

Comment: I have been having this issue since 2 months now. I can not recall if I did an update prior to this problem. What I did was to re-install windows from recovery and the issue was still there

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Power Settings in Windows, maybe there is something with that GPU that is requiring Power connected for external displays or Windows may has an ultra conservative power profile, thats disabling too much eg the GPU on battery. You might be able to tweak the settings and get it to work with Shorter battery life.

Answer (score 1):

For what you stated and the reviewed Video could be a Power Setting, a driver issue(I read you update them), but could also be a defective Video card.

*Below some hints/suggestions in how to tackle this. Before you proceed a full backup is also advised.*

For the Power settings For Windows 10:
Click the Windows Start menu and start typing Control Panel.
Open the Control Panel and Type Power in the Search Box.
Click in Edit power plan(window will open).
Click in Change advanced power settings(new window will open).
For troubleshooting purposes: 
In that window, set all the Power Battery settings as Plugged in.
If the issue is fixed, later attempt the changes 1 by 1 until you figure which is the one affecting your computer.

This could still be a driver issue, try also Older drivers.
I had an old laptop that only a far older driver was giving  less issues going to stand by that the updated ones. 
If you already attempted all the know drivers, skip to the last suggestion.

If the issue is the video card, try ruling out the Operating System(Windows 10 here for what I read) by loading other system like Linux in a flash drive or something.

I hope this helps,
Ramon

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve the issue by installing Linux. That is quite strange that it does not happen in Linux.Specially if I reset the laptop to the factory settings, the issue wont go away in windows.

I did apply all the methods suggested in the answers/comments but none did the trick.